# Why delay in update the count of edited posts

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Recently i have **edited some posts** of others & they got **approved** and my Reputation incremented by 2 for each.

But in my profile under `Activity Tag --> Impact` the **number of Edited posts** **not getting updated immediately** .

Is there any other approval required or like that ?

Comment: At a guess: caching. Give it some time.

Comment: That value is probably cached. It's not something that has a high priority for most people, so it doesn't warrant real-time updates.

Comment: @BilltheLizard You mean: [this](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) , *right* :)?